# How to trigger a created checkbox change event c#

Tags: c#, events, checkbox, datagridview

I created these checkboxes in my gridview to allows my users to select several rows. My problem is when the checkboxes are clicked they are suppose to store info for each one clicked. I placed breakpoints inside and the event is never triggered. Is this something I need to call in order to have this event run? I was under the impression it was like any other event where it just ran upon triggering it. I haven't found a generic help for these type of issue, it seems to be more specific problems. Do you have nay reference to help or any suggestions on how to allow my event to trigger properly?

On form load this is established

```
ckBox = new CheckBox();
//Get the column header cell bounds
Rectangle rect = this.dropdeadGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
ckBox.Size = new Size(18, 18);
//Change the location of the CheckBox to make it stay on the header
ckBox.Location = rect.Location;
ckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ckBox_CheckedChanged);
//Add the CheckBox into the DataGridView
this.dropdeadGridView.Controls.Add(ckBox);
```

Then this is where I declare what happens in the chkbox_CheckChanged Event

```
var rows = dropdeadGridView.Rows;

for (int j = 0; j < this.dropdeadGridView.RowCount; j++)
{
    this.dropdeadGridView[0, j].Value = this.ckBox.Checked;

    bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(dropdeadGridView.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value); 
    if (checkBoxValue)
    {
        values += rows[j].Cells[2] + ",";
        CurrentOrders = values;
    }
}
this.dropdeadGridView.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using a windows application

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-checkbox.htm

this link is telling how to add checkboxes in gridview. When changing selection the grids events like afteredit,validateedit etc will fire.

We are coding at there by checking the column number(if the column number matches with check box column number) do the operations which you mentioned in event at there

I'm less experianced in winforms and i used C1FlexGrid only(Equivalent will be there in windows grid also)

Answer (score 0):

Add an unhook event call, before hooking the event.

```
ckBox.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(ckBox_CheckedChanged);
```

Mostly your problem will get solved